# Python All vs All Ratio Comparison on Big Data Set (>19000 rows) Keeps Crashing

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, bigdata, bioinformatics

I've been doing some research on gene expression and drug interactions for some time now, and was recently asked to run an analysis on the entire human genome (>19000 rows). Essentially what my program does is take ratios of all of the expression data and correlates that to some drug information (the last 9 lines of the file).

What is happening is that every time I run my code, my computer is crashing. Is there any obvious way to make this work without having to run it on an entirely new machine? I'm working remotely so that's not really a possibility at this point. I'm using a relatively new macbook pro runnning python the terminal. My code is below, let me know if anything needs clearing up. Thank you for your help!

Edit 1: A coworker mentioned using Amazon Web Services to run this. Does that sound like a viable option? The setup seems a little complex to just run this Python script from what I have seen so far.

Edit 2: Here is an example of what some of the input file looks like:The rows continue down for the 1970 genes and the columns continue across for 57 different cell lines.

```
              WT     Mut    Mut     Mut
              WT     Mut    Mut     Mut
Cell lines  BR:MCF7 BR:MDA_MB_231   BR:HS578T
            BR:MCF7 BR:MDA_MB_231   BR:HS578T
5-HT3C2     -0.27   0.99    0.7 -0.42
A1BG-AS1    1.36    -0.15   0.87    1.7
A1CF        -0.14   -0.18   0.15    -0.1
A2LD1       0.62    -0.59   -0.29   2.45
A2M        -0.38    -0.4    -0.24   -0.39
A2ML1       -0.11   -0.13   -0.13   -0.12
A2MP1       0.31    0.65    1.2 0.03
A4GALT      1.99    0.41    -0.75   0.19
A4GNT       0.28    0.08    1.08    0.74
AAA1        -0.27   -0.25   -0.19   -0.16
AAAS        1.16    -1.46   -2.06   -1
AACS        0.73    0.11    -1.11   -2.08
```

**code**

```
import csv
import numpy
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

Reader = csv.reader(open('/Users/_57_genes.csv', 'rU'))

fout = "/Users/ratio_correlations_whole_genome_6232014.csv"

fileout = open(fout, 'w') #open file

#Create lists of lists including averages
Label = []
Resistance = []


for row in Reader:
    if len(row) == 0 or row[0] == '':
        continue
    else:
        Resistance.append(map(float, row[2:]))
        Label.append(row[0])



Ratios = []
Name = []

for index, i in enumerate(Resistance[0:-9]):
    gene = []
    Name1 = []
    for index2, j in enumerate(Resistance[0:-9]):
        r = []
        if j == i:
             continue
        for k in range(len(i)):
            if j[k] == 0:
                fraction = 0
            else:
                fraction = (i[k]/j[k])
            r.append(fraction)
        Name1.append('%s VS %s' %(Label[index], Label[index2]) )
        gene.append(r)
    Ratios.append(gene)
    Name.append(Name1)



for index, i in enumerate(Ratios):
    GeneName = Name[index]
    for index2, k in enumerate(i):
        Comparitor = GeneName[index2]
        #print k
        fileout.write('%s, ' % (Comparitor))
        for avg in (Resistance[-9:]):
            correlate = pearsonr(k, avg)
            fileout.write('%0.6f, %0.6f, ' % correlate)
        fileout.write('\n')

fileout.close()
```

Comment: 19,000 rows is big? I don't think so!

Comment: is your syntax formatted correctly at the `for index2, j in enumerate(Resistance[0:-9]):` row and after? This looks like is should be indented.

Comment: Sorry that was an error in pasting my code, should be fixed now. The code works as I've used it many times before on smaller datasets (around 80-100 rows).

Comment: The output is what's big, since I am taking the ratio of each set of gene expressions to one another so it will be greater than 19,000^2.

Comment: Look at **Name** and **Name1**. You try to store a lot of entries in these lists (~10^8) - Have you checked if you run out of memory? You probably will have to think about a solution that does not need to store information for your all pairs. Instead you might want to calculate all required statistics for each pair and write them out in one single step.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming a 64-bit architecture here; 32-bit code for data this big would run out of address space before running out of memory… I've measured sizes of objects using the `pympler` module available from pypi.)

You're building two 2d arrays that has 19000*19888=360981000 items. The name array itself contains that many strings. Each string object in Python takes at least 40 bytes, plus you need to add at least 8 bytes for the object pointer… which means this array takes at least 13GB.

Even more fun is with the other array: The other array takes at least 112 bytes per item (a list of at least one double takes 104 bytes, 8 bytes for a pointer), which is another 37GB.

Does you computer have 50GB of RAM? If not, you need to seriously rethink your code. Do you really need all the values to be stored at the same time? Maybe you can instead use a different algorithm which, instead of taking values from a table, computes the necessary values only on demand (when they're actually needed)?

Maybe instead of python lists you could use `numpy` arrays, which are much more efficient in memory (8 bytes per item for an array of doubles vs. 32 bytes).

Getting an AWS machine seems like a quick solution assuming you can pay for the most expensive  ones from their offer. Note that the exact memory requirements *will* be bigger—they depend on the string lengths, implementation details of python lists (exponential scaling algorithm used by them adds additional overhead to make list resizes work quickly), etc.

Also, one remark unrelated to the algorithm. Computing 360981000 p-values rarely makes sense from statistical point of view. Remember that to make this procedure scientifically valid, you'll most probably need to apply a multiple-test correction to p-values. With that many p-values the correction will be enormous and might invalidate any insights you'll get from the procedure (e.g. to get a 0.05 adjusted p-value you'd need to observe an unadjusted p-value below 0.0000000002).

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you explain what is really `i`, an `j`. And you don't seem to use `m` on this piece of code.

You also leave the file open the whole process instead of closing when you finished reading it. And you open the output file long before you really need it, (you could also consider to append the results to the file). And although I am not familiar you could use a generator instead of an iterator if it a problem of memory. Another consideration to your data structure is your code could be a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file. Could you post some lines of the input file?

What is the "crash" message?

Comment: Hi there,

i and j and gene expression values ranging from roughly -5 to +5. The last 9 lines of the file are similar but they are what's called sensitivity data for a panel of drugs, which is what I am correlating the ratios to.

You're right, I don't use m here (removed).

I am not getting a crash message, the terminal and essentially my entire machine gets hung up. It's possible if I just kept it running for a week it would complete the script, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Answer (score 0):

To help the troubleshooting, have a look at the `Activity Monitor` from OSX when you run you program, especially at the memory consumption tab.
You can observe the python process and its used memory, and look at the total available memory.

As hinted by some posts, you might have a memory problem. 
Generators will streamline the processing and save time/memory.